# Inserting geometry into spatialite - no geometry

Tags: python, spatialite

I have created a test spatialite database and I am having trouble inserting geometry into the table. I have successfully created the geometry column in the table and then I run the insert command. The weird thing is that it runs without error, and the attributes get passed in, however the geometry column is empty when I view it through a ODBC connection, as well as no geometry coming through in QGIS.

My code to create the table:

```
with sqlite3.connect(r'somedatabase.sqlite') as conn:

    conn.enable_load_extension(True)

    conn.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')")
    conn.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData()")

    c = conn.cursor()


    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gid(gid_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                latitude REAL, longitude REAL)""")
    c.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('gid','the_geom', 4283,'POINT','XY')")
    conn.commit()
```

And this is the code to create the geometry

```
someGeometry = [(150.895,-33.961),(150.896,-33.959),(150.893,-33.960)]
for longitude,latitude in someGeometry:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO gid(gid_id,latitude,longitude,the_geom)
                 VALUES(NULL,?,?,GeomFromText('POINT((%f %f)',4283))""" %(longitude,latitude),
                    (latitude,longitude,))

conn.commit()
```

I have also tried to remove the python string formatting by inserting only 1 point with specific coordinates like this

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO gid(gid_id,latitude,longitude,the_geom)
                 VALUES(NULL,?,?,GeomFromText('POINT((150.895,-33.961)',4283))""",(latitude,longitude,))
```

Comment: I'd suggest not inserting "NULL" as `gid_id`. The WKT you are trying to interpolate is bogus (`'POINT((%f %f)'` perhaps should be `'POINT(%f %f)'`). The last entry is bogus too (`'POINT((150.895,-33.961)'` is not valid WKT - perhaps you wanted `'POINT(150.895 -33.961)'` ?).  To debug this further, try showing the exact string you are trying to execute. I'd also suggest using `SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1)` to do the insert in a transaction which will save some time.

Comment: @BradHards Ah man, I was looking at it for ages, the sql is going to be it. Definitely an Extra bracket or two in there. I'll check when I'm back at work. Thanks.

Comment: Extra comma and extra bracket in the last bit of code.

Comment: I believe that your GeomFromText is not right. Have you tested it? I would do `select GeomFromText(('POINT(150.895 -33.961)'),4283)`

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it's wrong, I think what's happened is I have tried so many different combinations I have completely stuffed it. Not going to test until tomorrow. It's a pretty stupid question now it's been pointed out. However I'll leave it up because there is no warning that anything was going wrong with the insert.

Comment: I guess there is no error to warn about really if you look from the database side. GeomFromText just returns NULL and nothing gets inserted.

Comment: Yep, tested, thats all it was thanks both, I feel like such an idiot. @user30184 is there any documentation where it states if an invalid WKT is entered that NULL is returned?

Comment: Invalid WKT always returns null in spatialite, and I believe in postgis.

Comment: @BradHards if there documentation that states this, it would be great if you added it as an answer along with your first comment. I think it would be helpful for other users, I searched for ages trying to work out what was going wrong.

Comment: It is not documented in https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html nor in http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html.  However, while Spatialite accepts any string or even numbers and just returns NULL, PostGIS has better error reports, like `select ST_GeomFromText('foo'); ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "fo" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry`.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is trying the same, you can use geopandas with the to_file arguments to write to spatialite.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf = gpd.GeoDafaFrame([(0,150.895,-33.961,Point(150.895,-33.961)] columns=[gid_id,latitude,longitude,the_geom],geometry="the_geom")

gdf.to_file("somedatabase.sqlite", driver="SQLite", spatialite=True, layer="gid")
```